# JSON Web Tokens resetting express server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express, jwt

I'm creating a demo MEAN app and everything was going well I could Add and Authenticate Users and Add, Delete and Update Messages but after I implemented web token I can only view and delete messages when I try to add a new message I get this error.
The message is still added to my mongodb database but it stops the server.
I was trying to add my code from the components but I'm not allowed as I get a message saying that my post is mostly code and I need to add more information.

```
zone.js?fad3:2935 POST http://localhost:3000/message?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7Il9pZCI6IjVhNWRiMmFjYmVkMWQ3MmZmOGQzMDM3YSIsImZpcnN0TmFtZSI6IkpvaG4iLCJsYXN0TmFtZSI6IkRvZSIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiJDJhJDEwJHZmMVQ2S0VCeVZBSE9qSkRyQWg0WC51N3NHYXZZVXNQSHZyOHFNTllydVdJL3lZZXBKR0ZhIiwiZW1haWwiOiJqb2huQGRvZS5jb20iLCJfX3YiOjksIm1lc3NhZ2VzIjpbXX0sImlhdCI6MTUxNjEwMjM1NSwiZXhwIjoxNTE2MTA5NTU1fQ.6Kj1TcprqWRQIAZ9GSDHLxIbf_9DzPhx5qomv6QtxfA net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Message Route

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

let User = require('../models/user');
let Message = require('../models/message');

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    Message.find()
        .populate('user', 'firstName')
        .exec( (err, messages) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occurred',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Success',
                obj: messages
            });
        });
});

router.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    jwt.verify(req.query.token, 'secret', (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                title: 'Not Authenticated',
                error: err
            });
        }
        next();
    })
});

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    let decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);
    User.findById(decoded.user._id, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred',
                error: err
            });
        }
        let message = new Message({
            content: req.body.content,
            user: user
        });
        message.save((err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occurred',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            user.messages.push(result);
            user.save();
            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'Saved message',
                obj: result
            });
        });
    });
});

router.patch('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    let decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);
    Message.findById(req.params.id, (err, message) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred',
                error: err
            });
        }
        if (!message) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'No Message Found!',
                error: {message: 'Message not found'}
            });
        }
        if (message.user != decoded.user._id) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                title: 'Not Authenticated',
                error: {message: 'Users do not match'}
            });
        }
        message.content = req.body.content;
        message.save((err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occurred',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Updated message',
                obj: result
            });
        });
    });
});

router.delete('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    let decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);
    Message.findById(req.params.id, (err, message) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred',
                error: err
            });
        }
        if (!message) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'No Message Found!',
                error: {message: 'Message not found'}
            });
        }
        if (message.user != decoded.user._id) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                title: 'Not Authenticated',
                error: {message: 'Users do not match'}
            });
        }
        message.remove((err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occurred',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Deleted message',
                obj: result
            });
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Message Service

```
import { Http, Response, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

import { Message } from "./message.model";

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
    private messages: Message[] = [];
    messageIsEdit = new EventEmitter<Message>();

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    addMessage(message: Message) {
        const body = JSON.stringify(message);
        const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
            ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
            : '';
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/message' + token, body, {headers: headers})
            .map((response: Response) => {
                const result = response.json();
                const message = new Message(
                    result.obj.content,
                    result.obj.user.firstName,
                    result.obj._id,
                    result.obj.user._id);
                this.messages.push(message);
                return message;
            })
            .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }

    getMessages() {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/message')
            .map((response: Response) => {
                const messages = response.json().obj;
                let transformedMessages: Message[] = [];
                for (let message of messages) {
                    transformedMessages.push(new Message(
                        message.content,
                        message.user.firstName,
                        message._id,
                        message.user._id)
                    );
                }
                this.messages = transformedMessages;
                return transformedMessages;
            })
            .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }

    editMessage(message: Message) {
        this.messageIsEdit.emit(message);
    }

    updateMessage(message: Message) {
        const body = JSON.stringify(message);
        const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
            ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
            : '';
        return this.http.patch('http://localhost:3000/message/' + message.messageId + token, body, {headers: headers})
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }

    deleteMessage(message: Message) {
        this.messages.splice(this.messages.indexOf(message), 1);
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
            ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
            : '';
        return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/message/' + message.messageId + token)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code please.

Comment: After messing around with it a bit more I found out that the problem comes from when I push the new message to the user.messages array without this it works fine..